# Windows 10 Pro Hyper-V Manager Missing

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I have the full release version of Win10 Pro (64bit) as a fresh install to a laptop that I previously used as a Hyper-V server running Win8.1 Pro.

I have selected to install all Hyper-V features from Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features. This prompted a reboot which was done with no errors reported. If I now view the "Windows Features" dialog then I can see the "Hyper-V" checkbox and child check boxes are all ticked. However, when I search for "Hyper-V" from the search toolbar I can see no sign of Hyper-V manager. Anyone know a way around this problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Windows search seems to have some problems indexing sometimes in Windows 10. Is the file actually installed? Check %windir%\System32\virtmgmt.msc and see if the file exists and if the snap-in will launch for you.

Comment: Yes this is the problem, indexing is pretty bad

Answer (score 1):

Before the first execution my start menu search could not find Hyper-V-Manager as well.

So, after launching Hyper-V once through one of these options, Windows search now always finds it (not sure which one helped immediately)

- Either use the shortcut *Hyper-V-Manager* in the folder `Windows Administrative Tools` of the start menu
- Or type `virtmgmt.msc` in the start menu and execute it

Answer (score 0):

I looked looked for %windir%\System32\virtmgmt.msc and it wasn't there.  I installed Microsoft Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) as described on [www.petri.com](http://www.petri.com)

https://www.petri.com/workaround-finding-missing-hyper-v-tools-windows-10

Comment: Can you expand upon the which parts you used from your link? This is in case the link is ever removed in the future. Please see [answer].

Comment: The link referenced by @politus explains exactly my experience with missing Hyper-V Manager and the suggested solution to install the RSAT tools solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If it's missing just because Windows Indexing is being rubbish, then you might be able to find the shortcut in the Public Start Menu folder: `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\Hyper-V Manager.lnk`

From there you can right-click it and pin it to the Taskbar, which is what I usually do.

Answer (score -2):

Expanding on Politus' Comment and Burgi's request.
I already had RSAT tools installed before I tried installing Hyper-V manager.  I could not find HyperV Manager in any of the locations I had found online (Program Data, Start Menu, System32, or through MMC as mentioned in the petri link.)

I downloaded and installed the x64 RSAT Tools again and when my computer finished rebooting. Hyper V Manager was available through the Start Menu.

I say 'again' because I had already installed RSAT tools.
Today I installed: WindowsTH-RSAT_WS2016-x64.msu
I had installed: WindowsTH-RSAT_TP5_Update-x64.msu on 10/3/2016 and tried to install HyperV on 10/19.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: What you experienced was suppose to happen since you recently updated to Version 1511.  Of course you should install the 1607 version of the .msu in question.